# Clicking noise in front passanger wheel

Tags: noise

I have a 2003 Jeep Liberty. All of a sudden while driving I heard a clicking noise coming from the front passanger side tire area. The noise speeds up as I do and gets quieter when I speed up. It sounds like a card in a bike tire although the sound changed a little when I first sped up. Around 45mph it got very quiet although it was still there. Turning doesn't make a difference. The CV is good and the lugs are all tight. I have never heard this noise before in my life. Any ideas as to what it could be would be a huge help. OK I checked the tires and see nothing stuck in them. I did take it on the road again today and noticed that going over bumps slowly to hear any difference in noise it makes almost a grinding sound...sort of like a shock would when it's worn out. Then twice I heard a noise that sounded like it was coming from the back almost a binding noise like a brake grind sort of. I know sometimes a wheel bearing can "throw" it's noise. Could it be my wheel bearing or does it seem like 2 separate issues? Any other ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Check and see if there is a rock stuck in the tread.

Answer (score 1):

check to see if you have a stone or nail stuck in your tyre would be first move put your steering on full lock and rotate tyre slow by hand checking your tread they dont allways deflate if you pick up a screw or nail

Comment: Thanks for answering. I checked but unfortunately nothing in the tire, but at least it ruled something out